# PHP file() vs fopen()+fgets() performance debate

Tags: php, performance, file, fopen, fgets

I am in process of rewriting some scripts to parse machine generated logs from perl to php
The files range from 20mb~400mb
I am running into this problem to decide if I should use file() or fopen()+fgets() combo to go through the file for some faster performance.

Here is the basic run through,
I check for file size before opening it, and if file is larger than 100mb(pretty rare case, but it does happen from time to time) I will go the fopen+fgets route since I only bumped the memory limit for the script to 384mb, any file larger than 100mb will have chance causing fatal error. Otherwise, I use file().

I am only going through the file once from beginning to the end in both method, line by line.

Here is the question, is it worth it to keep the file() part of the code to deal with the small files? I don't know how exactly file() (i use the SKIP_EMPTY_LINE option as well) works in php, does it map the file into the memory directly or does it shove line by line into the memory while going through it?  I ran some benchmark on it, performance is pretty close, average difference is about 0.1s on 40mb file, and file() has advantage over fopen+fgets about 80% of the time(out of 200 test on the same fileset).

Dropping the file part could save me some memory from the system for sure, and considering I have 3 instance of the same script running at the same time, it could save me 1G worth of memory on a 12G system that's also hosting the database and other crap. But I don't want to let the performance of the script down also, since there is like 10k of these logs coming in per day, 0.1s difference actually adds up.

Any suggestion would help and TIA!

Comment: You could just write a simple script to run it x times one way and output the time taken whilst watching memory usage then run it again x times the other way. That would enable you to find out how they both performed with your data on your systems and which was the winner.

Comment: I think you'd be better off writing one implementation and making it work well. Reading one (or n) line(s) of the file at a time, interpreting/translating and writing the output to disk or w/e it's going will work for all file sizes. Maintaining another solution adds complexity and developer time, which is always precious. It sounds like memory size is your limiting factor and you haven't hit a barrier for execution time. I'd like to give you more ideas on improving performance, but I feel I would be off base; can you elaborate on what the input and output look like/need to do?

Comment: Input is some giant size machine generated log that has data everywhere and not in a uniform row format, and I need to parse different data off it. So Into more detail, for each type of data, it has its own class/object to keep track of what stage its at, and once a complete row of data has been formed, dump it to a csv file that later on will be bulk upload to database. Memory itself, if I can get significant performance boost, I don't mind to dish out the 1Gb. But base on the benchmark with php microsecond difference. Execution time wise, I am kinda on the edge of it.

Comment: and jumping to to memory route doesn't seem will get me far from that edge. Read file into memory and process used to be fast in perl, but since the data is getting more and more complex, I need object supports to maintain a clean code, and I am not really good with perl at all, thus switching to php. I think my question is more on how file() in php actually map the file into memory, if it goes through it from beginning to end once, I think the answer is clear, I should drop that idea :x correction to the last comment. file() has ~.1s advantage 80% of time , otherwise .2~3s behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest sticking with one mechanism, like `foreach(new \SplFileObject('file.log') as $line)`. Split your input files and process them in parallel, 2-3x per CPU core. Bonus: lower priority than database on same system. In PHP, this would mean spawning off N copies of the script at once, where each copy has its own file list or directory. Since you're talking about a rewrite and IO performance is an issue, consider other platforms with more capabilities here, eg Java 7 NIO, nodejs asynchronous IO, C# TPL.