# Read line by line or get all in memory and read (file)

Tags: php, memory, fopen, fgets

I wondered whether it would be the best and fastest solution in PHP between:

1. Read line by line directly with fgets() (while !EOF).
2. Get all the content of the file into an array of string and read each element.

Thank you !

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I have a big txt file and I need to detect a certain line (with regex) . So Which one is the fastest ?

Comment: How big is the file? If it's a bigger file it's probably better to read it chunked, instead of as a whole blob.

Comment: Read it line by line. It might be ever so slightly less efficient, but it covers you for a file size that will exceed your memory limit - and it covers you for loads of users potentially *not* exceeding your memory limit, but still hosing the server through using too much memory at once.

Comment: Try both and see. They're both simple to implement.

Comment: Yes I know @fiskfisk but I would like to know the best practice

Comment: best practise depends on too many factors such as filesize, available memory, required speed of response, etc that there is no such thing as best practise in this circumstance

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454520/php-file-vs-fopenfgets-performance-debate

Comment: Best practice is the one that produces most readable code. As for the speed, fgets is probably faster, given proper chunk length.

Comment: Ok thank you for all! I'll read it line by line with fgets in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compose both methods. Read as much as possible data with `fread()` (untill you reach per script memory limit). Then split this data on lines and process it. Then read file again. Thus you decrease disk usage and can manually controll script RAM usage.